# Apps restarts again when App/Build gone in background while uploading images from Camera /Gallery or open any other APP

Tags: android, file-upload, camera, gallery, miui

I am new in android studio recently,I have make a program related to uploading images from camera and gallery And that program working smoothly with all other devices but when **when i update my Redmi note 7 device version from MIUI 11.6 to MIUI 12.02 (android version 10 )then its create problem like.**. (***our App close the currently using fragment or restarts the app*** ) i have tried  many solution:
1.remove restriction from the background for that App
2.try app lock for stay the APP in background etc.. but no result found.

**kindly help me thanks in advance..**.

Comment: This is perfectly normal behavior. It is not unique to your Redmi device. It has been around since Android 1.0. Your app's process will be terminated when it is not in the foreground, and that might happen fairly quickly. Your app needs to be able to handle this. See https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/process-lifecycle?hl=en and https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#asem and https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/saving-states#onsaveinstancestate.

Comment: thanks sir for answering me but my App starts from starting  when Apps goes in the background and then it creates null pointer exception when it comes back on ONActivityResult method after selecting the images from Camera/Gallery for not initialising the XML views layouts field ...and when i tested same thing on other devices then it will work smoothly

Comment: Your app has bugs, apparently. You will need to fix the bugs. If you cannot figure out how to fix the bugs, ask a separate Stack Overflow question with a [mcve]. That example should include the full stack trace for the `NullPointerException`, along with the code that is generating the exception.